# ReferenceError: process is not defined when requiring Shelljs in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6, shelljs

I am trying to require shelljs in my core React component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';

const shell = require('shelljs');

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log("First component mounting");
        console.log("First component mounting");
        return (
            <Header />
        )
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I run

```
webpack build
```

I get no errors, then I run my server and I get the following console error.

I'm using jekyll as my server side. Currently transitioning from the normal jekyll implementation to React only.
React is well implemented cause i tested the Header component before importing the shelljs module

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I'm new to using modules in javascript, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you add the code/commands you are using to run your server too, please?

Comment: Updated description

Comment: yeah, everything i can see looks fine, but i'm not very familiar with jekyll so i might not be much help. sorry.

Comment: I am not really experience but as reactJs is completely frontend, the backend I use shouldnt even matter. Jekyll is only used to serve the HTML where the Components will be mounted. Correct me if Im wrong

Comment: yeah, but if you said you built it without any errors first, i guess i'm confused on where that error is coming from

Comment: @Goamaral Why do you need `shelljs` in your component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to guess you don't *really* mean to use your `shell` constant since you haven't referenced it anywhere within your React component. `Shelljs` looks like it's a tool specifically for the command line.

As for your error:

`process` is a global variable in the Node environment. Since React runs in the browser, and your component is going to render in the browser, `process` will not exist in the context of your component.

Try opening the Chrome DevTools (or the developer tools for whatever browser you use) and type in `process`. You'll get a TypeError because it doesn't exist. What does exist, however, is the global `window` variable.

Now, open the command line and type `node` to open the Node.js REPL.
Type `process` here, and you'll see that it's an object holding a lot of properties and values. Next, type `window` and press enter. `window` does not exist here because it only exists in the browser.

(Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice to exit Node btw. :])

Comment: I want to try to simulate what Jekyll does. I want to have a folder with my posts and see if it's empty, if it isnt, I want to grab all the files as strings and build my stuff from that.

Comment: I saw something about what you just said. Thanks for the explanation. Btw any ideas of how can I achieve it?

Comment: found out i can do what i wanted with jekyll static files.(https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/) Will try to incorporate a ruby script to count the number of files.

Comment: how to fix it ?